Hugh MacColl and Meinong's position on existence
After researching the Russell and MacColl debate, at first I didn't know about MacColl, but I became very interested in him, so I continued to research him and eventually found out more about theory of existence. In the process, I found the content of Russell and Meinong's argument about existence here. However, as I continued reading this article, it felt like MacColl and Meinong had similar views. In other words, I thought it could be summarized as Russell vs MacColl and Meinong. Is this right? And I would like to take this opportunity to learn more about existence.

Russell claims as much in On Denoting:"Mr. MacColl regards individuals as of two sorts, real and unreal; hence he defines the null-class as the class consisting of all unreal individuals. This assumes that such phrases as 'the present King of France', which do not denote a real individual, do, nevertheless, denote an individual, but an unreal one. This is essentially Meinong's theory, which we have seen reason to reject because it conflicts with the law of contradiction." However, your own source cites several authors who say that "Russell’s Meinong is not Meinong."

Hugh MacColl after One Hundred Years.

@Conifold Thank you for your comment! I know what my mistake was.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your comment! I will see the paper you linked.

@Conifold Hello, this may be a difficult request, but is it okay if I ask you a favor? I'm still confused about Russell, MacColl, and Meinong's positions on the above topic. Could you explain the positions of the three characters?

It is subtle and I am afraid I cannot do it within reasonable time. But Rahman, the author of your linked article, has another one, where he compares and contrasts MacColl and Meinong (pp.11-13). He concludes that MacColl probably never read Meinong and was not a Meinongian in spirit either despite some similarities. His metaphysics was much more conventionalist and pragmatic. What Russell did was assimilating MacColl's symbolic existence to Meinong's subsistence.

@Conifold I know it might be inconvenient, but thank you very much for writing a comment.
